# running php script to convert html to pdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

I have a form which I want to convert to pdf. I want to use fpdf to do that
My html code is as follows:

**page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<header>
   <h1 align='center'>Welcome  </h1>
</header>
<section align = 'center'>
   <h2> Register </h2>
   <form action = "form.php" method = "post"
      <p>
        <label>First Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name = "first_name" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Last Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Gender :</label>
        <select name="gender">
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>
         <label>Date of Birth :</label>
         <input type="date" name="dob" />
      </p>
         <label>Mobile :</label>
         <input type="text" name="mobile" />
      </p>
      <p>
         <label>Email :</label>
         <input type="text" name="email" />
      </p>
   <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />

   </form>
   </section>

   </body>  
   </html>
```

I have created a php script to convert the form to pdf once the register button is clicked the php is :

**form.php:**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
{

$f_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$l_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$dob=$_POST['dob'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",16);
$pdf->Cell(10,10,"welcome {$f_name}",1,0,C);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"Name :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"$l_name",1,0);

$pdf->Cell(50,10,"gender :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"$gender",1,1);

$pdf->Cell(50,10,"Mobile :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"$mobile",1,1);

$pdf->Cell(50,10,"Email :",1,0);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"$email",1,1);

$pdf->output();

}
?>
```

I am running this on XAMPP and have created a folder called demo in htdocs(where the html file, php file and fpdf folder is there), however when I run html file on browser and click register, it simply displays the php code in the php file rather than generating the pdf

**The files are in htdoc of XAMPP files in folder demo like this:**

[image]

**When I run page.html(click on register):**

[image]

**It shows me this:**

[image]

Why is it not generating a pdf?

Comment: is your register file a `.php` extension or `.html` ?

Comment: what's a register file? Th following code is all what I have coded

Comment: ok good. I see the edits.

Comment: how do I create that?

Comment: I  see one issue so far, on this line: `$pdf->Cell(10,10,"welcome {$f_name}",1,0,C);` you have a `C` aka constant, but you didn't define it anywhere in the `php` file. So define it or remove it: `$pdf->Cell(10,10,"welcome {$f_name}",1,0);.` Secondly, are you able to execute any other `.PHP` files? your code worked fine for me, after I removed the `C.`

Comment: I just mentioned how I am running it in the post, It doesn't work for me or let me put this way, I don't know how to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to output to a file:

```
string Output([string dest [, string name [, boolean isUTF8]]])
Description
```

Send the document to a given destination: browser, file or string. In the case of a browser, the PDF viewer may be used or a download may be forced. 
The method first calls Close() if necessary to terminate the document.

see http://www.fpdf.org/

Look for the Manual menu

Description

Send the document to a given destination: browser, file or string. In the case of a browser, the PDF viewer may be used or a download may be forced. 
The method first calls Close() if necessary to terminate the document.
Parameters

dest
Destination where to send the document. It can be one of the following:

```
I: send the file inline to the browser. The PDF viewer is used if available.
D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
F: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a path).
S: return the document as a string.
The default value is I.
name
The name of the file. It is ignored in case of destination S.
The default value is doc.pdf.
```

Comment: I added to my answer.  You should check out the site I linked to to learn how this library works.  Add the code after you complete the creation of the document

Comment: maybe what @joelgoldstick mean is, change your `$pdf->output();` to `$pdf->Output('your file name.pdf', 'I');` CMIIW